# Character Encoding: â?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, encoding, extjs, character-encoding

I am trying to piece together the mysterious string of characters â?? I am seeing quite a bit of in our database - I am fairly sure this is a result of conversion between character encodings, but I am not completely positive.

The users are able to enter text (or cut and paste) into a Ext-Js rich text editor.  The data is posted to a severlet which persists it to the database, and when I view it in the database i see those strange characters...

1. is there any way to decode these back to their original meaning, if I was able to discover the correct encoding - or is there a loss of bits or bytes that has occured through the conversion process?
2. Users are cutting and pasting from multiple versions of MS Word and PDF.  Does the encoding follow where the user copied from?

Thank you

---

website is UTF-8
We are using ms sql server 2005;

SELECT serverproperty('Collation') -- Server default collation.
Latin1_General_CI_AS

SELECT databasepropertyex('xxxx', 'Collation') -- Database default
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

and the column:

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
text    varchar no  -1                  yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

> The non-Unicode equivalents of the
>   nchar, nvarchar, and ntext data types
>   in SQL Server 2000 are listed below.
>   When Unicode data is inserted into one
>   of these non-Unicode data type columns
>   through a command string (otherwise
>   known as a "language event"), SQL
>   Server converts the data to the data
>   type using the code page associated
>   with the collation of the column. When
>   a character cannot be represented on a
>   code page, **it is replaced by a
>   question mark (?)**, indicating the data
>   has been lost. Appearance of
>   unexpected characters or question
>   marks in your data indicates your data
>   has been converted from Unicode to
>   non-Unicode at some layer, and this
>   conversion resulted in lost
>   characters.

So this may be the root cause of the problem... and not an easy one to solve on our end.

Comment: Missing info that can be pretty relevant: DBMS, DB charset, web site charset, language of the information (English, French, Japanese...).

Comment: One more test you can do: type `–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›€™` in Microsoft Word and try to find out at which point of the process it becomes corrupt.

Answer (score 3):

`â` is encoded as 0xE2 in ISO-8859-1 and windows-1252.  0xE2 is also a lead byte for a three-byte sequence in UTF-8.  (Specifically, for the range U+2000 to U+2FFF, which includes the windows-1252 characters `–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›€™`).

So it looks like you have text encoded in UTF-8 that's getting misinterpreted as being in windows-1252, and displays as a `â` followed by two unprintable characters.

Comment: which would explain the two question marks...  i hope it is sql server performing  the conversion...

Comment: @dan04 +1! I did the same research and was not able to reach the conclusion! Can you recommend a resource to find a character by byte sequence rather than Unicode code point?

Comment: @akaphenom, I'm afraid that SQL Server takes a valid character and strips two thirds of the information *before* making the conversion. It's not identifying the source as UTF-8.

Comment: Alvaro are ou suggesting that even with nvrchar, SQL Server cannot persist utf-8?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580 Store the actual UTF-8 data on the server using the BINARY/VARBINARY/IMAGE columns. - what a mess...

Comment: @akaphenom What I mean is that there is probably an additional problem apart from having different charsets: your servlet receives UTF-8 user input and sends it to SQL Server but SQL Server doesn't appear to know it's UTF-8. I'm not especially familiar with these two technologies but I suppose there's a way to instruct Java so it can handle input properly and set a proper charset for the DB link.

Answer (score 2):

This is an something of an educated guess that you're just experiencing a naive conversion of Word/PDF documents to HTML.  (windows-1252 to utf8 most likely)  If that's the case probably 2/3 of the mysterious characters from Word documents are "smart quotes" and most of the rest are a result of their other "smart" editing features, elipsis, em dashes, etc.  PDF's probably have similar features.

I would also guess that if the formatting after pasting into the ExtJS editor looks OK, then the encoding is getting passed along.  Depending on the resulting use of the text, you may not need to convert.

If I'm still on base, and we're not talking about internationalization issues, then I can add that there are Word to HTML converters out there, but I don't know the details of how they operate, and I had mixed success when evaluating them.  There is almost certainly some small information loss/error involved with such converters, since they need to make guesses about the original source of the "smart" characters.  In my isolated case it was easier to just go back to the users and have them turn off the "smart" features.

Answer (score 0):

you're storing unicode data that uses 2 bytes per charcter into a varchar type columns that uses 1 byte per character. any text that uses 2 bytes per chars will have 1 byte lost when stored in the db.

all you need to do is change varchar column to nvarchar.
and then change sql parameters you're using in code of course.

Comment: Would I need to make a change to the collation of the column as well?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clear: if the browser is good enough, a form in a web page can accept any Unicode character you can type or paste. If the character belongs to the HTML charset, it will be sent as is. If it doesn't, it'll get converted to an HTML entity. SQL Server will perform the appropriate conversion and silently corrupt your data when a character does not have an equivalent.

There's not much you can do to fully fix it but you can make a workaround: let your servlet perform the conversion. This way you have full control about it. You can, for instance, compile a list of the most common non-Latin1 characters users paste (smart quotes, unicode spaces...), which should be fairly easy to identify from context, and replace them with something else better that `?`. Or you use a library that makes this for you.

Or you can switch your DB to Unicode :)

Comment: Per your comment in dan04's response - I have found the wiki fairly interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 it lays out the code-pages pretty simply.  not sure that is what you are looking for

Comment: @akaphenom Wikipedia's article is an excellent resource but it doesn't contain a full character table (for obvious reasons). I often use http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ but you can only search by Unicode code point.