# Special character 'Â' inserted in JObject controller parameter

Tags: json, rest, json.net, ascii

I have a POST Rest API which is receiving a json from body

```
controllerFunction([FromBody] JObject payload)
```

I am giving a json from postman which has a property called "Non­Critical_XYZ". When I am receiving the json in controller one extra "-" is getting added in JObject payload. The property is coming as "Non-Critical_XYZ". When I am taking the payload in excel it is showing like Special character 'Â' inserted for the property "NonÂCritical_XYZ".

Below are the headers I am sending with the request

[image]

Comment: And what is the problem? Can you show the code that creatres JObject or json?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the RAW post headers + body?  Chances are there is something wrong with the encoding in teh headers and/or the encoding is being interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Perhaps the original JSON property name had a non-breaking space or other non-ASCII between `Non` and `Critical` and is getting messed up by a wrong encoding choice.  For similar questions see [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461907), [Character Encoding: â?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4547149), [How to convert â€™ to apostrophe in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10888040), [why Special characters apostrophe and others shows like this â€™,Â in HTMl file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30739625)